# a problem in grub bootloader

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I'm a new Linux user and I'm facing an annoying problem with my customized grub boot-loader, suddenly after running the OS for a while -maybe two days or a week- my PC stack in keep repeating this screen which containing the manufacturer logo -sorry that i don't know it's name- and don't display the grub menu to choose between Ubuntu or windows but when I try to boot from my external hard drive that contain backups for the whole PC the grub menu appears and I can then boot the OS. this problem faced me about 6 times and what i do is recovering the nearest backup data but this cause me to loose all my new data. I always try to run the command  ($sudo update-grub) but nothing changes. could you help me please?
I'm still not familiar with Linux commands and consents so please give me some details.

Comment: Show us your "customized grub boot-loader". The manufacturing Logo is likely from BIOS, during post boot. Grub would be after that. Are you saying it never goes to the next step? Or that it does, but the grub menu is not visible?

Comment: Logo may now be from Ubuntu 20.04 as it shows UEFI/BIOS logo with Ubuntu at bottom for start of boot. I am finding and seens several others that if you turn off os-prober & use 40_custom for boot stanzas like I do, grub menu does not show. I have to press escape (if UEFI, shift if old BIOS). For me that is fine as it works. Not sure I have seen fix to always show menu.

Comment: Found this which may depend on other settings in /etc/default/grub. `GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu`  Default is `hidden`.

Comment: what is happening with me is that instead of showing the grub menu the screen terns black and the manufacturer logo, which is Hp, appears again, as if the PC restarts itself.

Comment: the only way to boot my operating systems is to boot from  my external hard drive -which only have a backup of my PC. I didn't save the grub files on this external hard drive, I checked it and found only my backup data.

Comment: and what I find is that when i plug in this hard drive, pres F9 (during the manufacturer logo is on) and choose to boot from the external hard drive the grub menu appears and i now can boot the operating systems which are on the internal hard drive